# compressord starting up every time I turn on my MacBook

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) running macOS 10.12.3 and have Compressor 4.3 installed. Every time when I restart my Mac, there are 2 processes called compressord, and CompressorHelper that got automatically started and causing my MacBook to use the discrete graphics card (which consumes a lot of battery power). One way to get rid of them is to open Compressor and quit it afterward. But it is annoying since every time I startup my Mac I need to do this process.

Is there a way to stop these two processes from opening up every time I start up my Mac? (Possibly without reinstalling Compressor as that takes up a very long time to do for me)

Comment: Why are you restarting so often?

Comment: @samh OK, it is either because my computer freezes (or other glitches) or I need to debug a script.

Answer (score 4):

This problem cropped up for me when I used Compressor after not having used it in a long time. I've found that if I launch and quit Compressor after starting my computer then the process goes away but I haven't yet figured out how to make it stop running on boot.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to check is your login items under Users and Groups -> your username in System Preferences. If Compressor isn't in the login items list then look in your LaunchAgents folder at ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ . If you decide to go the second route, make sure to only delete the compressor launch agent.

Note: I don't know what compressor is exactly so this may not be the most accurate.

Answer (score 1):

No, the solution resides in here

/Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems

There's what keeping your GPU on all the time through the 'compressord' process.

Comment: It would help to provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: Oh! Of course. Well, this one problem was burning through my Macbook Pro's battery, all while holding the machine from restarting and/or shutting down entirely. Figured it was what is in /Applications/Compressor.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems because since the GPU was always on I downloaded gfxCardStatus app to help me monitor and perhaps turn off the GPU, and lo and behold, it told me I couldn't turn off my GPU because some 'compresord' process was preventing it from doing so. Look on Activity Monitor for this process, found it, search its path, and deleted what was in there. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

In Compressor, go to Preferences > Advanced > Reset Queue...

From there, try both Reset Queue and Repair Compressor.